# javascript replace comma with dot / paypal

Tags: javascript, replace, paypal

I have a Paypal button: Paypal allows only a DOT in the field: amount, tax, shipping

```
<form target="paypal" name="paypal" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="paypalbutton">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="email.test@paypal.de">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="testname">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="order234">
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="2,25">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE">
<input type="hidden" name="tax" value="1,10">
<input type="hidden" name="shipping" value="10,20">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="www.test.com" >
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="www.test.com" >
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Bezahlung mit Kreditkarte via PayPal" alt="Bezahlen mit Kreditkarte via PayPal" class="btn btn-default">
</form>
```

only the three inputs need a DOT in the price! paypal allow only a DOT, not a COMMA

```
name="amount"
name="tax"
name="shipping"
```

here is a js for one input, but I need this for the three input:/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var point = document.forms[0].amount.value;
var comma = point.replace(/,/, ".");
document.forms[0].amount.value = comma;
</script>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to replicate the code that already works on one field to the other 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you not do the same for the others?  put that code into a function and send the name of the field through as an argument.

```
function change_comma(input_name){
  var point = document.forms[0][input_name].value,
      comma = point.replace(/,/, ".");
  document.forms[0][input_name].value = comma;
}

change_comma('amount')
change_comma('tax')
change_comma('shipping')
```

note that I am referencing the variable in the function using square brackets.  This allows you to reference the portion of the object contained within the variable.

Comment: this code dont work :/
OMG what a nice comment box...
so?
`   <script type="text/javascript">
    var point = document.forms[0].amount.value;
    var comma = point.replace(/,/, ".");
    document.forms[0].amount.value = comma;

    var point = document.forms[0].tax.value;
    var comma = point.replace(/,/, ".");
    document.forms[0].tax.value = comma;

    var point = document.forms[0].shipping.value;
    var comma = point.replace(/,/, ".");
    document.forms[0].shipping.value = comma;
    </script>
`

Comment: I forgot the period before value, changing

Answer (score 0):

Rather than relying on JavaScript to transform the `,` to a `.`, do it on the server side.  After all, some clients might have JavaScript disabled.

The fields are all `hidden` input fields, so presumably generated by server-side code.

Further, I would suggest never storing actual payment amounts in the HTML code.  Doing so makes it possible for someone to use a browser plugin (or simply the F12 tools on most browsers) to change the amount they are about to pay.

Comment: Excellent point on the server side validation!  I have seen payments pushed through after being changed b the user.  It is no good when you push a payment well below the cost because a user could change what they had to pay.